# Segfault with pointer to char inside struct, ANSI C code

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm having a strange behavior with the following simple ANSI C code. I have a pointer to a char inside a struct, and somehow, i have bad pointers, nulls and segfaults. Am i doing something stupid?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

#define MAX_ENTITIES 10

typedef enum
{
    COMPONENT_NONE = 0,
    COMPONENT_DISPLACEMENT = 1 << 0,
    COMPONENT_VELOCITY = 1 << 1,
    COMPONENT_APPEARANCE = 1 << 2
} component_t;

typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
} Displacement;

typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
} Velocity;

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
} Appearance;

typedef struct
{
    int entities[MAX_ENTITIES];

    Displacement displacement[MAX_ENTITIES];
    Velocity velocity[MAX_ENTITIES];
    Appearance appearance[MAX_ENTITIES];
} scene_t;

typedef struct
{
    int active;
    scene_t *current_scene;
} game_t;

unsigned int entity_create(scene_t *scene)
{
    unsigned int entity;

    for (entity = 0; entity < MAX_ENTITIES; ++entity) {
        if (scene->entities[entity] == COMPONENT_NONE) {
            printf("Entity created: %u\n", entity);
            return entity;
        }
    }

    printf("Error! No more entities left!\n");
    return MAX_ENTITIES;
}

unsigned int scene_add_box(scene_t *scene, float x, float y, float vx, float vy)
{
    unsigned int entity = entity_create(scene);

    scene->entities[entity] = COMPONENT_DISPLACEMENT | COMPONENT_VELOCITY | COMPONENT_APPEARANCE;

    scene->displacement[entity].x = x;
    scene->displacement[entity].y = y;

    scene->velocity[entity].x = vx;
    scene->velocity[entity].y = vy;

    scene->appearance[entity].name = "Box";

    return entity;
}

unsigned int scene_add_tree(scene_t *scene, float x, float y)
{
    unsigned int entity = entity_create(scene);

    scene->entities[entity] = COMPONENT_DISPLACEMENT | COMPONENT_APPEARANCE;

    scene->displacement[entity].x = x;
    scene->displacement[entity].y = y;

    scene->appearance[entity].name = "Tree";

    return entity;
}

unsigned int scene_add_ghost(scene_t *scene, float x, float y, float vx, float vy)
{
    unsigned int entity = entity_create(scene);

    scene->entities[entity] = COMPONENT_DISPLACEMENT | COMPONENT_VELOCITY;

    scene->displacement[entity].x = x;
    scene->displacement[entity].y = y;

    scene->velocity[entity].x = vx;
    scene->velocity[entity].y = vy;

    return entity;
}

void update_render(scene_t *scene)
{
    const int mask = (COMPONENT_DISPLACEMENT | COMPONENT_APPEARANCE);
    unsigned int entity;
    Displacement *d;
    Appearance *a;

    for (entity = 0; entity < MAX_ENTITIES; ++entity) {
        if ((scene->entities[entity] & mask) == mask) {
            d = &(scene->displacement[entity]);
            a = &(scene->appearance[entity]);

            printf("%s at (%f, %f)\n", a->name, d->x, d->y);
        }
    }
}

void game_init(game_t *game)
{
    scene_t scene;

    memset(&scene, 0, sizeof(scene));
    game->current_scene = &scene;
    game->active = 0;

    scene_add_tree(game->current_scene, 5.0f, -3.2f);
    scene_add_box(game->current_scene, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    scene_add_ghost(game->current_scene, 10.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

void game_update(game_t *game)
{
    update_render(game->current_scene);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    game_t game;

    memset(&game, 0, sizeof(game));
    game_init(&game);

    while (game.active == 0) {
        game_update(&game);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `game_init`, you are declaring a local variable of type `scene_t`. Once `game_init` ends, *this variable no longer exists* - you cannot use it correctly outside that function, but that's what you try to do when you access the scene inside your `game_t` variable.

If you want to create a scene_t which can be used outside of the function, you need to allocate the memory for it manually by using

```
scene_t* scene = malloc(sizeof(scene_t));
```

...and then working with it as a pointer instead.

Comment: Should i also apply memset to it? Or a malloc is enough?

Comment: @vinnylinux: You should still use memset since you don't know what might be in that piece of memory. Alternatively, you could use calloc instead of malloc to have it cleared during allocation.

Comment: What is faster? malloc and memset or calloc?

Comment: @vinnylinux: I would expect the performance to be more or less the same, and therefore not worth worrying about. If you really are in a situation where you need every last cycle, profile it and see which is better.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Also, do i have to malloc char *name inside the Appearance struct? And, when freeing a struct, do i also have to free it's members, or is this done automatically?

Comment: @vinnylinux: In your example code, no, because the strings you assign to name are constants in the executable, so the pointer is always going to be valid. In general, however, whenever you create a variable and need it to survive after the end of the function it is created in, you need to allocate it properly.

Comment: Regarding freeing: you need to free everything you malloc/calloc, and you need to do it manually, once the variable is no longer needed by anyone. If you don't always know when that is, you can use techniques like reference counting to allow you to free objects at the right time.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving a local address, when function goes out of scope "scene" will be destroyed.

```
scene_t scene;

memset(&scene, 0, sizeof(scene));
game->current_scene = &scene;
```

You should instead allocate scene

```
scene_t* scene = malloc(sizeof(scene_t));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not allocating a `scene`:

```
scene_t scene;

memset(&scene, 0, sizeof(scene));
game->current_scene = &scene;
```

the `scene_t` object here is on the stack and that memory will be reclaimed once you exit from the function. You should instead use

```
scene_t *pscene = malloc(sizeof(scene_t));

memset(pscene, 0, sizeof(scene));
game->current_scene = pscene;
```

this way the memory will be allocated from the heap, surviving the exit from the function.

You will need later to `free` this memory once done with the object.

Comment: When i free a struct, e.g: free(game), do i have to free it's members as well?

Comment: Do i have to malloc char *name inside the Appearance struct?

Comment: @vinnylinux: you don't `free` a struct, you `free` a pointer. For the memory manager routines `malloc` and `free` memory is just bytes and they don't care about what is the content. The struct `game` contains a pointer to another block of memory and you should take care of it before deallocate a `game` structure if you allocate it with `malloc`. On the other hand `scene` instead contains only arrays of other structs (and no pointers to other blocks of memory) and therefore nothing is needed for them.

Answer (score 1):

You also don't assign a value to `scene->appearance` when you are creating a new ghost.  When you then try and print the appearence later you'll get whatever the pointer happens to point to printed ou.